# how to visualize segmented labels in a already existing graph?

Tags: python, graph, deep-learning, semantic-segmentation

I am working on a project where I have to segment the image using multi-class segmentation (3 classes) on microscopic images.

Now let's say that I am segmenting solid, liquid and gas images (this is an example made up for asking  the question because  I am not allowed  to discuss  anything about the project :( ), I have pixel wise segmented solid, liquid  and gas. But  now, once I have segmented these images, I want to put the  results on already existing graph. for example, if the water in images is  segmented as red in color, then I want to interpret this  result in already  existing graph with the red color as an indicator(I have  added images as example),  same goes for blue  color  as solid.

Can anyone please help me  how to do this? I am using u-net   architecture for  semantic  segmentation. This is my first question, although I have tried to explain the question to best of my ability, please  let me know if more information is needed to help me answer this question.

**graph of the solid, liquid and gas state**:
[image: graph of the solid, liquid and gas state]

**segmented image**:
[image: segmented image]

Comment: I think you've done a fine job explaining what you want, but I think this might not really be considered an on-topic question for StackOverflow, just because it's dealing more with high level concepts than actual code implementation. Here is a list of StackExchange sites that specifically have a focus on Machine Learning - see if any of the sites linked in this post might be better suited to answering your question (also please read their guidelines before posting): https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms

Comment: You're welcome, and I will say that you _may_ get help here but you could be more likely to get help on more specific sites.